# mat is not a numerical tuple : openCV error

Tags: python, opencv

i have write down a code showing error i ma not getting it: Please help:
 Its showing mat is not a numerical tuple:

```
import cv
import cv2
capture = cv2.VideoCapture("j.3gp")

while(1):

    _, frame1 = capture.read()

    grayImage1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, frame2 = capture.read()
    grayImage2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    differenceImage = cv2.absdiff(grayImage1,grayImage2)
    thresholdImage = cv2.threshold(differenceImage,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imshow("Difference Image", differenceImage)
    cv2.imshow("threshold Image", thresholdImage)
    cv2.imshow("Image", frame1)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff


Error arising :
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desk.py", line 15, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("threshold Image", thresholdImage)
TypeError: mat is not a numerical tuple
```

Answer (score 27):

I got the answer myself: `cv2.threshold` returns two values and adding an extra variable at the start rectifies the error like given below as I did in `capture.read()`

```
thresholdImage = cv2.threshold(differenceImage,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

should be:

```
_ ,thresholdImage = cv2.threshold(differenceImage,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Comment: ^^ ah, yes. it also returns the threshold value (in case you're using otsu)

Answer (score 2):

> _ ,thresholdImage = cv2.threshold(differenceImage,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

could also be

```
thresholdImage = cv2.threshold(differenceImage,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)**[1]**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_,img_otsu = cv.threshold(img_2,127,255, cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
```

use this also